# C# Solar System, trouble with planetary orbit math

Tags: c#, animation, matrix, graphics, simulation

I am writing a Solar System simulation program; I am but a beginner using C#.

I am using OnPaint on a custom control to draw my graphics on the form. I am having problems with the animation as, instead of having the planet rotate around the sun (a fixed point in the centre of the control), it is rotating around the point in which the planet should be. However, this point is still rotating around the centre of the control.

I have declared these variables at the top of the custom control:

```
private color col1;
private float angle;
private double r1, r2, ex, why;
```

Below is the code in OnPaint:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

        AnimationControl anim = new AnimationControl(); 

        Planet sun = new Planet(50, 60);
        sun.drawSun(pe);

        angle += 0.01f;
        if (angle > 359)
        {
            angle = 0; 
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.Rotate(angle, MatrixOrder.Append);
        matrix.Translate(SandboxForm.ActiveForm.Width / 2,
            SandboxForm.ActiveForm.Height / 2, MatrixOrder.Append);
        g.Transform = matrix;

        r1 = 200; 
        r2 = 100; 
        double diameter = 40; 
        col1 = Color.Red;
        SolidBrush bru2 = new SolidBrush(col1); 
        ex = ((SandboxForm.ActiveForm.Width / 2) - diameter - (sun.getSunRadius())) + (r1 * (Math.Cos(angle))); /
        why = ((SandboxForm.ActiveForm.Height / 2) - diameter - (sun.getSunRadius())) + (r2 * (Math.Sin(angle))); 
        g.FillEllipse(bru2, (float)ex, (float)why, (float)diameter, (float)diameter); 
        Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of matrix.Rotate and matrix.Translate?

Comment: yes, that doesn't solve my problem. It's more or less the same as it is currently when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to simplify your code as there are missing classes etc.  However in this you can see that it now does what you want.

If you try this code, you'll see that the order of Rotate and Translate do matter, but it wasn't having any effect when you tried my suggestion because you're painting before you apply the transform.

Notice also that I have `using` around my matrix, that's because you should dispose of it when you're finished with it.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;


        angle += 0.2f;
        if (angle > 359)
        {
            angle = 0;
        }
        using (Matrix matrix = new Matrix())
        {
            matrix.Rotate(angle, MatrixOrder.Append);
            matrix.Translate(300, 200, MatrixOrder.Append);

            g.Transform = matrix;
            pe.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(50, 60, 50, 50));
        }


        Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.